# Decoding %E9 to utf8 fails

Tags: java, utf-8, decode

I'm having some trouble decoding some encoding char.
What i need to decode is the %E9, i have a string like this D%E9bardeur and degr%E9
What i do in my java class, is the following:

```
try
      {
        System.out.println(o);// test
        o = URLDecoder.decode((String) o, "UTF-8");
      }
      catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e)
      {
        e.printStackTrace();
      }
```

After this operation, what i get is

```
D�bardeur and degr�
```

The very same happens when i dont decode to utf-8

Any advice?
thx

Answer (score 7, accepted):

%E9 is not UTF-8.

The correct way to decode this would be:

```
URLDecoder.decode((String) o, "ISO-8859-1")
```

Answer (score 1):

By `%E9`, could you mean there is a byte in your string that evaluates to hex `E9`? Because if so, that flags as "multibyte" in UTF-8, and there are 2 more "continuation bytes" (within the correct range) that follow.

Because remember, UTF-8 is a variable length encoding, so some code points (character values) are represented by 1 byte, some by 2, 3, etc.

If you have a string you're treating as UTF-8 and `E9` is encountered, the next 2 bytes need to be in the correct range. For example, in this string, `00`, which follows `E9` is not a valid continuation byte:

http://hexutf8.com/?q=0x640x650x670x720xe90x00

Here's an example where `E9` in a string *is* followed by the correct 2 bytes:

http://hexutf8.com/?q=0xc20xa90xe90x810xaa

And the appropriate character is represented.