# UnicodeError in Python

Tags: python, unicode, ascii

I have encountered a problem when outputting data from my script:

```
UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character u'\xe9' in position 14: ordinal not in range(128)
```

This is the code that outputs the data:

```
zipped = zip(list_1, list_2, list_3, list_4, list_5)

with open('my_file.csv', 'rb') as infile, open('my_out_file.csv', 'wb') as outfile:
reader = csv.reader(infile)
writer = csv.writer(outfile)
for i, row in enumerate(reader):
    row.extend(zipped[i])
    writer.writerow(row)
```

After some searching I realise that I have to manually encode it into UTF8, but I can't really figure out how. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Read about [CSV encoding](https://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html) support. There is an example UnicodeWriter right there in the CSV module reference doc.

Comment: you could use [unicodecsv](https://github.com/jdunck/python-unicodecsv) module which takes care of a lot of unicode edgecases.

Comment: `\xe9` is not an invalid UTF-8 character, but if that byte is encountered, there are specific rules as to what bytes can follow for properly encoded UTF-8. See: http://stackoverflow.com/a/26942594/183677